# Raspberry Pi backup server (Mac & Windows)

Tags: partition, backup, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I would like to set up my raspberry pi model B and my 2TB hard drive as a backup server for both my windows pc and my mac. I would like to partition my hard drive such that 300GB is for mac time machine backups, 300GB is for windows backup image and the remaining space is a partition to be used for file sharing.

Pi is running Raspbian OS

Can anyone guide me on how to go about partitioning my drive with my Pi?

Thanks!

Been following this guide (but it doesnt fit my needs anymore): https://raymii.org/s/articles/Build_a_35_dollar_Time_Capsule_-_Raspberry_Pi_Time_Machine.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide presumes that the disk is located at /dev/sda (Normal location if you only have 1 disk connected). It does use "fdisk" instead "parted"

Open a terminal prompt and type the commands below:

First step is to get root activated (This saves you from having to type "sudo" before each command:

```
su -
```

And type your root password to login as the root user.

If the disk is mounted, you will need to unmount the disk by running:

```
  ummount /dev/sda
```

Now once it's unmounted, you can run the command:

```
 fdisk /dev/sda
```

Which opens the partition table of the disk for editing.

Enter `m` to get the help information.

You will need to delete any existing partitions. To see if there are any, enter `p`. This will print a list of the partitions on the device.

To delete the partition, enter `d` and the number of the partition. You will need to repeat this command until all the partitions are deleted.

Next enter `n` which is the command for creating a new partition. Enter `p` for a Primary Partition which is the default.

It will ask you for the sector information. For the first partition enter the default start sector (Just leave it blank to use default I believe) and then for the end sector enter `+300G` which creates a 300gb partition.

Repeat the `n` command again for the windows backup disk, then again for the file sharing partition but this time, use the default end sector to max out the disk space.

Write the new partition table to the disk by entering `w`.

To create a ext4 filesystems on these new partitions run:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda2
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda3
```

These commands assume that you numbered the partitions 1-3 and want to use the ext4 format which is what most linux distributions use.

To mount these file systems, you need to create a folder to mount each partition in. I will use /mnt as an example but you can use any location.

```
mkdir /mnt/timemachine
mkdir /mnt/windowsbackup
mkdir /mnt/filesharing
```

Then run the following to mount the partitions:

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt/timemachine
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /mnt/windowsbackup
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda3 /mnt/filesharing
```

These should now be ready to use for your purposes.

Comment: wow thank you very much for the step by step instructions. I appreciate it very much!

Comment: No problem - you're welcome! :)